# The Ax-Grothendieck theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, model-theory

I am new to algebraic geometry.
My question is simple, as title suggests it's about a grothendieck theorem. I mean, I don't understand what the statement of theorem exactly is. For simplicity of my understanding I have used the case of 1 variable.

I understand that theorem as follows:-
If K[x] is a ring of polynomials in one variable and K is an algebraically closed field then if for all f belongs to K[x] is one to one then it's onto.

I understood it in this way and suspect many mistakes in it. Correct me by notifying the mistakes and also I have another question. How can some function be one to one and onto at the same time. So I also request an example clarifying my question

Comment: Do you mean to say "For algebraically closed $K$, for every $f\in K[x]$, if $f$ is one-to-one then it's onto"? Your phrase "if for all $f$ belongs to $K[x]$ is one-to-one..." has some grammar problems, leading to ambiguity.

Comment: dear Rahul, you ask how a function can be both one-to-one and onto at the same time; are you familiar with the notion of a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection)? (a bijection is precisely a function that is both one-to-one and onto.) for example, the identity function on any set $X$ (ie the function $X\to X$ that takes each $x\in X$ to itself) is an example of a bijection

Comment: Atticus Stonestrom, so is this theorem says that such a function is bijective?